# Comparing a view's tag to an integer

Tags: android, tags, integer, compare

I'm trying to compare an array of integers to the tags of imageviews I have uniquely made.

using this line:

```
if(grid[i][j] == buttons[k].getTag()){
```

I know im on the right tracks, but I can't figure out if i need to cast it or use a method. I know its a simple question, but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How did you set the tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your Tag is rather a String than an Integer.

If that's the case convert your Integer toString() and check if it equals().

Answer (score 25):

Tag is an Object, so put an `Integer`:

```
/*
 * UseValueOf
 * ----------
 * Priority: 4 / 10
 * Severity: Warning
 * Category: Performance
 * 
 * You should not call the constructor for wrapper classes directly, such as`new
 * Integer(42)`. Instead, call the valueOf factory method, such as
 * Integer.valueOf(42). This will typically use less memory because common
 * integers such as 0 and 1 will share a single instance.
 */
//MyView.setTag(new Integer(42));
MyView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(42));
```

Then retrieve the value like this:

```
int tagValue = (Integer)MyView.getTag();
```

Comment: I think you don't have to use 'Integer.valueOf(number)' part. Isn't just 'setTag(42)' work for this?

Comment: This is misleading, you cannot cast a `view` to an `Integer`

Comment: @Darrell Tag is not a View, it's an Object.

Comment: I tried this exact method and it gives an error stating "An Object of View cannot be cast to an Integer"

Comment: For getTag() - Class casting is not allowed on click in Android so [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10663187/4120911) is a more suitable solution

Comment: thanks ... i will use this tag method to compare some images of playing cards... work great... really appreciate your answer with setTag and getTag

Answer (score 13):

You have to convert buttons[k].getTag() in integer.

Do this:

```
if(grid[i][j] == Integer.parseInt(buttons[k].getTag().toString())){
```

Comment: Very easy fix to my problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You pass in an integer and get in an index variable. Here is the code snippet

```
int Index = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
System.out.println(Index);
```